# How to disable Monaco editor in angularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, monaco-editor

I am trying to disable Monaco editor. I am using `angularJs`. Using `monaco-editor` directive, I tried to make it disable with `ng-disabled` but not working. Because it supposes to add on `text-area`.

My template:

```
<monaco-editor ng-model="data"
   ng-disabled="isActive"
   language="xyz"
   ng-change="update()"></monaco-editor>
```

I tried to see in `monaco-editor` component:

```
bindings: {
            readonly: '@?',
            disabled: '@?',
            ...
```

but don't know what I am missing. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
editorInstance.updateOptions({ readOnly: true }) or 
editorInstance.updateOptions({ readOnly: false })
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit for the answer :) is there any other way, we can achieve this. we are using a lot of places actually. So can we achieve this any directive or some generic way which we can do with template itself?